# Sharing GUI variables without static variables

Tags: java, user-interface, pass-by-reference

Currently I have a GUI that has options for the user to select on how the program should run:

```
//Inside GUI.java, start button has clicked -> send all objects to Main class
private void startButtonClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Main.setMain(selectedObj.getItemAt(selectedObj.getSelectedIndex()));
    Main.setOwnCar(userName.getText().trim());
    Main.enableNaps(weSleep.isSelected());
    Main.useOwnHouse(useOwnHouse.isSelected());
    if (weSleep.isSelected()) {
        Integer minSleep = (Integer) minVal.getValue();
        Integer maxSleep = (Integer) maxVal.getValue();
        Main.setSleepMinMax(minSleep, maxSleep);
    }
    setVisible(false);
}
```

When the start button is clicked I want to pass all the variables from the GUI into the main class. The only way I knew how to do it was to use getter/setters but they have to be static:

```
static void setSleepMinMax(int min, int max) {
    sleepMin = min;
    sleepMax = max;
    Log("Sleeping debug: [min->" + min + "] [max->" + max + "]");
}

//Inside an infinite loop I have this which is at the top
//until the GUI is closed it does not start the rest of the program
if (gui.isVisible()) {
    Log("Waiting for GUI vars");
    return 1000;
}
if (!getOwnCar.isEmpty())
    Log("Using " + ownerCarName);
```

Most say avoid static variables. What is the correct way if I am unable to use a constructor because my main class is always running and the GUI is just a window that can be opened to change variables on demand? Perhaps pass by reference similar to C++?

Comment: why they have to be static?(you are not owner of Main?) who is most & why avoid? (how avoid, if you are not owner??) ...sry, it's not clear/too broad.

Comment: Java is always pass-by-value. That is, if an object reference is passed to a method, then the reference itself is copied. However, the object to which the reference points, is modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

The design it's up to your side. You could pass also the object reference or use some standard design patterns (GOF - singleton).

You could look also at:
[Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276740/how-to-re-use-value-in-different-functions/54278521#54278521)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PassVar {
private int mainVar = 0;
private MyObj myobj;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    PassVar pv = new PassVar();

    pv.new MyObj(pv);
    System.out.println("value="+pv.mainVar);
    pv.new ChangeValue(pv);
    System.out.println("value="+pv.mainVar);
    pv.new ChangeValue(pv);
    System.out.println("value="+pv.mainVar);

    pv.myobj = pv.new MyObj();
    System.out.println("myobj_i="+pv.myobj.i);
    pv.new MyObj(pv);
    System.out.println("myobj_i="+pv.myobj.i);
    pv.new MyObj(pv);
    System.out.println("myobj_i="+pv.myobj.i);

}
public void setMainVar(int i)
{
    mainVar = i;
}
    class ChangeValue
    {
        ChangeValue(PassVar pv)
        {
            pv.setMainVar(new Random().nextInt() %100);
        }
    }

    class MyObj
    {
        public int i=-1;
        MyObj() {}
        MyObj(PassVar pv)
        {
            i = 10+new Random().nextInt(10);
            pv.myobj = this;
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
value=0
value=11 (random between -99 ... 99)
value=77

myobj_i=-1
//set obj.ref. in PassVar from MyObj
myobj_i=18 (random between 10 ... 19)
myobj_i=12
```

Comment: Note that `new Random().nextInt() %100` yields an uneven distribution of values.

Comment: just need some value there and any random was fine. But even so it's not necessary uneven distribution. Basically 1000 time using new Random() should get the same distribution  using 1000 nextInt() on Random().

Comment: It's better to use `new Random().nextInt(100)`.

Comment: The only advantage I could see is not using % and not having negative numbers, but regarding on distribution I do not see any improvements.  The idea is that any "random" number get by any "random" method is assumed to be random, so even getting one by one  regardless of method should have the same distribution.Thank for remind that nextInt() supports parameters.

Comment: One issue with taking the result modulo `n` is that the maximum result may not be a multiple of `n`. Consider a source of randomness that outputs a number `[0, 97]`. Taking that result `mod 10` would result in disproportionately fewer `[8,9]` results, since `98` and `99` are missing from the initial result set.

Comment: @CollinD, yes that is true for 1-97, but in this case it's taken by full range so it's the same distribution.

Comment: @TraianGEICU I don't think `MAX_INT` is usually a multiple of 100. The effect is certainly mitigated by the size of the range, but it still exists. But as you said, it's not super important here.

Comment: @CollinD,, 2,147,483,647  is not multiple of 100 but also is a large number so in the worst case at limit you have fair distribution. Practically, you get a fair distribution even with MAX_INT. Taking care even that any generator it's not perfect so the result will be the same. I could accept your reasons based on MAX_INT of not being perfectly fair (math speaking) but still the distribution  is fair enough due to large number.

Comment: @CollinD,@MC. Didn't think initially of fairness of random, but thanks for raising the issue. Good topic.

Answer (score 0):

Write it to a property file and read it from there.So that when next time one uses it again he can have the previous values.