# How to pass methods in the child class to the Main class in Java

Tags: java, console-application

I have  some problem in my Code. I have 3 classes the Main class,Parent Class, Child class.

I'm a bit confused with the constructor part. what I did was to have a parent constructor and child constructor.

I created a method named addEmployee 
and then trying to pass this method to the main class
    What I'm trying to do is to pass the method " addEmployee Method in my child class to my main class but it seems like there is an error when I tried to instantiate an new object at the main class.

Anyone can help me on this??

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


MAIN CLASS
public class EmployeeInformation {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("");
String Name = sc.next();

        Employee myemp = new Employee(Name);
    myemp.getName();

    myemp.addEmployee();
    String name = sc.next();


    }


}

PARENT CLASS
package employeeinformation;
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String ID;
    private String address;
    private String gender;
public Person(String Name , String ID, String address, String gender)
{
    this.name = Name;
    this.ID = ID;
    this.address = address;
    this.gender = gender;
}

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ID
     */
    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    /**
     * @param ID the ID to set
     */
    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the address
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * @param address the address to set
     */
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    /**
     * @return the gender
     */
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    /**
     * @param gender the gender to set
     */
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}

CHILD CLASS

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package employeeinformation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author salomon
 */
public class Employee extends Person {
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    private String employmentType;
    private String empID;
    ArrayList<Employee> el = new ArrayList<Employee>();


 Employee(String Name, String ID, String address, String gender, String employmentType, String empID) {
        super(Name, ID, address, gender);
        setEmpID(empID);
        setEmploymentType(employmentType);

    }



    /**
     * @return the employmentType
     */
    public String getEmploymentType() {
        return employmentType;
    }

    /**
     * @param employmentType the employmentType to set
     */
    public void setEmploymentType(String employmentType) {
        this.employmentType = employmentType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the accesscard
     */


 public void addEmployee()å
{
 System.out.println("Enter your Full Name");
 String name = sc.next();
 System.out.println("Enter your NRIC/ID");
 String ID = sc.next();
 System.out.println("Enter your Address");
 String address = sc.next();
 System.out.println("Enter your Gender");
 String gender = sc.next();
 System.out.println("Enter your Employment Type");
 String employmentType = sc.next();
 System.out.println("Enter your Employment ID");
 String employmentID = sc.next();


Employee empobj;
empobj = new Employee(name, ID, address, gender, employmentType, getEmpID());
el.add(empobj);
System.out.println(el);
}

 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee Details " + getName() + getAddress() + getID() + getGender(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    /**
     * @return the empID
     */
    public String getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    /**
     * @param empID the empID to set
     */
    public void setEmpID(String empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    /**
     * @param empID the empID to set
     */

}
```

Comment: could you show the error message ?

Comment: Your design needs some improvement. An `Employee` should be an entity class with information about _one_ employee. The `Scanner`, list of employees and the  `addEmployee()` method belong elsewhere, perhaps on `EmployeeInformation`.

Comment: I guess you are kinda right. no wonder when I keep trying to call the method but it seem like it cant find the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main method, you are using below constructor to create a new object.

```
Employee myemp = new Employee(Name);
```

But you don't have such constructor in your Employee class. Try adding below constructor to your Employee class

```
 Employee(String name){
    super(name);
    setName(name);
}
```

and below constructor to you Person class

```
public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Please note that you can use the constructor only declared in the object class. Else you can try to create an empty object and set the attributes to individual elements using setters as below in your main method.

```
Employee myemp = new Employee();
myemp.setName(name);
```

For this to work, you need to have an empty constructor in your Employee class as below

```
Employee(){}
```

Comment: I see, if I will to create a empty object. will it be like below public Employee() {
    this.name = name;
    this.ID = ID;
    this.address = address;
    this.gender = gender;
}

Comment: I under that the variable ( name, id, gender, address) is inherit from its parent class, person. so do I need to include those in the employee constructor?

Comment: im still abit confuse with contsructor. correct me if im wrong. the constructor created in the employee then when i insatiate in the main class then it depend on what is in the constructor of that sub class. is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to inherit the parameters of parent constructor in child class. As I mentioned in the answer, if you create a constructor in parent class(Person) with only name parameter, then you can have a constructor in your child class (Employee) with only one parameter.

Comment: If you want to create an empty constructor, it will look like Employee(){} and in the super class as Person(){}

Comment: Yeah, in Main class, or any other location, when you instantiate an object, you can only use constructors declared in the object. i.e, if I have declared a constructor with 2 parameters say name and age, then I must use both name and age to instatntiate that object, I can't use less or more parameters. But you are allowed to have multiple constructors with different number of parameters. i.e. You can have a constructor with 2 parameters say name and age, with 1 parameter say name, 3 parameters say name, age, gender. Which allows for flexibility in creating object.

Comment: But only criteria to have multiple constructors is you can't have different constructors of same size and parameter type. i.e. can't have 2 constructors with 2 parameters both being string in both constructors. Eg : can't have Person(String name, String address) and Person(String name, String gender). 
 But You can have Person(String name, String gender) and Person(String name, int age). Hope that answers. Thanks

Comment: icic. thanks a lot. I think I have a better understanding now. the parameters and size cannot be the same for multi constructors.

Comment: hi, i have tried to pass contructor from one class to another but it seems there is an error. like employee(String name, String id , String address) in the employee and in the main class i institnate as employee emp = new employee(name,id,address). im nt sure if did i make any mistake in any part.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code  `Employee myemp = new Employee(Name);` to `Employee myemp = new Employee(Name , address, gender, employmentType, empID);` Provide address, gender, etc to the Employee constructor.

(Or)

Create a single arg. constructor in the Person & Employee Classes.

```
public Employee(String name){
  super(name);
  this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example at [pass objects-vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296709/sharing-gui-variables-without-static-variables/54297838?noredirect=1#comment95417750_54297838) maybe it could help you.

But on title you do not pass methods(invoke them and get a result) , you pass objects or variables to other classes(instances).